# Execute SQL Query and At the Same time find the number of records returned

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have query something like this:

```
SELECT   YEAR,
         period,
         ROUND(a.NUMERATOR/b.total_sum, 0) avg_val FROM

(Select ... ) subQuery1,
(Select ... ) subQuery2

ORDER BY YEAR, period
```

I also want to know the number of records the query is returning.

How should I modify the query?

Comment: Add a new column, `count(*)` to return number of rows matching your query (if your provider doesn't already have a way of getting number of rows returned).

Answer (score 1):

I know that in SQL Server to get the number of rows affected by the SQL statement you should return `@@rowcount` from your query. In Oracle it should be something similar, like `sql%rowcount` i guess, according with this post:
http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20077

Also have look this post [Need a row count after SELECT statement: what's the optimal SQL approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243782/need-a-row-count-after-select-statement-whats-the-optimal-sql-approach)

Comment: This is something else. HanuAthena asked about SELECT, not UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the query returns N rows. Do you want the number N to be added to EVERY row?

I suppose not. Then you'll need a separate query for returning the number of rows in the results of your query. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(Select ... ) subQuery1,
(Select ... ) subQuery2
```

By the way, it's better to use a JOIN between subQuery1 and subQuery2 and not just a comma. A JOIN will make your query more readable.

Comment: there is GROUP BY clause that determines the no of records. Nope. I dont want the number N to add to every row. I just want the COUNT of records that returned by executing the query.

Comment: So use the query I gave you, this is what it does.