# How in MyBatis to map total count of rows into separate field?

Tags: java, count, mapping, mybatis, ibatis

Suppose we have the following mapping in MyBatis:

```
 <resultMap id="map_X" type="Wrapper">   
    <result column="....." property="totalCount" />     

    <collection property="someArray" ofType="hashmap">
        <result column="A" property="first" />
        <result column="B" property="second" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="mySelect" resultMap="myMap">
    SELECT A, B FROM myTable
</select>
```

How to set the count of rows in the query into the property **totalCount** of resulting **Wrapper** object.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be solved with SQL alone. MyBatis is not the issue here.

```
<select id="mySelect" resultMap="myMap">
   SELECT A, B, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable) AS totalCount
   FROM myTable
</select>
```

Not sure if your `resultMap` is correct since the id's in your `select` don't match.

Here is a thread with more [detailed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243782/need-a-row-count-after-select-statement-whats-the-optimal-sql-approach).

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is possible yet **a bad match** for MyBatis and SQL alike. I would solve this Java-side. e.g.:

```
public int getTotalCount() {
  return someArray.size()
}
```