# SELECT some column and count the rows in the same query

Tags: sql

I want to select some rows and want to return those rows plus an additional column that display the count of selected rows. I am using a derived version of sql that doesnot allow me use `OVER() AS` function as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243782/need-a-row-count-after-select-statement-whats-the-optimal-sql-approach) . I want something like for each element in selected column ,I want a count of it in entire table Like

For Initial column like this :

```
Fruits
Apple
Mango
Fruits
Banan
```

Final returned values :

```
Fruits NewColumnwithCount 
Apple   2
Mango   1
Apple   2
Banana  1
```

Like in selected colum called Fruits, Apple appear 2 times, banana 1 times and Mango 1 time (in the entire selected column called fruits)

Comment: Please add the tag for the DBMS do you use

Comment: I can't understand the connection between your sample data and your desired results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled , Like in selected colum called Fruits, Apple appear 2 times, banana 1 times and Mango 1 time (in the entire selected column called fruits)

Answer (score 2):

use a `GROUP BY` as:

`SELECT COUNT(FruitID), FruitName FROM Fruits GROUP BY FruitName;`

**UDPATE**

`SELECT FruitName, 
(select count(fs.id) FROM Fruits fs where fs.id = f.id GROUP BY fs.FruitName) as 'count' 
FROM Fruits f;`

The subquery will return how many times the selected fruit is present

Comment: But this will  group all Apples together , no ? I want each time apple appears as it is, with additional information of the count

Comment: ok I get it now...then use a sub-query for the count.  Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for window functions:

```
select fruit, count(*) over (partition by fruit) as NewColumnwithCount
from t;
```