# how to get row count from Tibco Direct SQL or JDBC Query activity

Tags: sql, tibco, ojdbc, tibco-business-works

In my Tibco process I have logic that map SQL query output only if the query returns less than 1000 records from Tibco "Direct SQL" or Tibco "JDBC Query" activity.

For now I am just running same query 2 times:

```
Select count(*) AS Count 
FROM my_table  
WHERE my_table.foo = 'bar'
```

if first query result less than 1000 I call same query for getting all the rows

```
Select my_table.* 
FROM my_table  
WHERE my_table.foo = 'bar'
```

The query is pretty heavy and I want to run it only once for performance purpose.

I found the solution from SQL side in the [Need a row count after SELECT statement: what's the optimal SQL approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243782/need-a-row-count-after-select-statement-whats-the-optimal-sql-approach)

I can use query like:

```
SELECT my_table.*, count(*) OVER() AS Count
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_table.foo = 'bar'
```

The problem is that adding count(*) to the query is also affecting performance.

I can map the query result to "Map Data" activity and then use count($Map-Data/pfx:my_element/) but I prefer to avoid additional not required maping for performance purpose.

The Tibco "Direct SQL" and Tibco "JDBC Query" are using Oracle (ojdbc7.jar) and DB2 (jt400.jar) drivers.

Is there any way to get the query output row count from tibco side without adding count to the query output?

Comment: What about using `fetch first 1000 rows only`?

Comment: 1000 is just an example. It can be changed in Tibco side.  Also I need  count of query records in process output.

Comment: I can map result to "Map Data" activity and then use count($Map-Data/pfx:my_element/) but I prefer to avoid additional not required maping for performance purpose.

Comment: So, Ideally I don't want to do any mappings or other additional activities in tibco side if query row count is more than N, but I need to know query row count in the process output. Just limiting query output won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got what I need. I can just use XPATH "count" function directly from  "SQL Direct" or  "JDBC Query" activities output

"JDBC Query": 
    count($JDBC-Query/resultSet/Record) < 1000

"SQL Direct": 
    count($SQL-Direct/jdbcGeneralActivityOutput/unknownResultset/row) <1000

[image: JDBC Query row count]